# What is academic protocol for citing a Tweet?

Tags: citations

Are there international standards for how a cited source should strive to be persistently discoverable?

A Tweet can be deleted.

Is using WaybackMachine / Web Archive better practice?

Comment: Same as citing any other online source?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Cite Tweet using Mendeley]

Ref: [Mendeley Web Citation Guide](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web-citation-guide/)